# Program that calculates the salary of each employee individually with a structure

Tags: c, arrays, structure

**The problem in hand:**

A worker needs to calculate his weekly salary, which is obtained from follows:

- if you work 40 hours or less per week is paid € 16 hour
- if you work more than 40 hours is paid € 16 for each of the
- first 40 hours and 20 € for every extra hour
- You will retain 15% in taxes and SS.

Make a program that collects data and display 5 workers, display the salary of each of them.

Define a function for collection of data and a function to calculate the salary worked.

**My approach till time**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define EMP 5
int i;
int j;
struct work
{
  char name[20];
  int hours[5];
  float salary[8];
} t[EMP];

int main(void)
{
  for(i=0;i<EMP;i++) //Bucle para recolectar los datos
  {
  printf("\nThe name of the employeer :  ");
    scanf("%s",t[i].name);
  printf("\nHow many hours he works :  ");
    scanf("%d",t[i].hours);

//    printf("\nThe man works %d",yoh_work[i].horas);
  }
  if(t[i].hours<40)
  {
    t[i].salary=t[i].hours*16; //(yeah im know this doesn't work
  }

}
```

after this, I am out of ideas. Please share the idea to procceed.

Comment: `c#` tag seems irrelevant. And this seems a homework.

Comment: You are accessing an array by index `i` outside of the loop which defines `i`. You also, for some reason, have an array of 5 integers for each worker's hours and 8 floats for the salary, but you're using them as if they were a single int/float.

Comment: @SonerGönül All questions here must follow SO rules and policies. Homework questions are fine as long as they live up to the site standards. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 0):

The point here is, you don't need an array for the `hours` and `salary` *inside* the structure. You only need one variable. After that, you need an array of structure variables, as you've done.

So, your structure should look like

```
struct work
{
  char name[20];
  int hours;      //notice here
  float salary;   //notice here
} t[EMP];
```

After that, You have to use loops to ask for user input to populate the fields for each employee (referenced by each variable of the `t` array) and calculate accordingly.

The algorithm do achieve this is like below,

1. Ask for employee name, store it in the `t[i].name`, `i` is the index.
2. Ask for the hours worked, store it in `t[i].hours`
3. Repeat 1 and 2 for the required number of times, (`5` times here)
4. check if the `t[i].hours` is `> 40`.

   4.1. if YES, calculate like (simplified, you should consider the *tax* related part while making actual calculation)

   `t[i].salary = ((float)40 * 16) + ((float)(t[i].hours - 40) * 20)`

   4.2. If NO, calculate like

   `t[i].salary = ((float)t[i].hours * 16);`
5. Do this for all the structures.
6. Finally using another loop, print the result.

Hope you got the idea. Please try implementing, if you run into issues, come back, we'll be there to help. :-)